# The same posts shows to times

Tags: php, laravel

[image: Layout]

The problem here is that red marked news ARE THE SAME. And what I want to do here is to make sure that the new posts wont repeat themselves. Because now as you can see the same posts shows up two times before another is posted.

This is the code:

```
    @extends('app')

@section('content')


   <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">

          @if(count($latest))
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <a href="/post/{{$latest->slug}}/{{$latest->id}}">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="{!! url($latest->image) !!}" alt="" style="padding: 0px; height: 400px; width: 720px"></a>
            <h2 class="post" style="margin-top: 0; color: #666">

              @foreach($latest->category as $cat)
                <a style="color: red; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 13px" href="/categories/{{$cat->name}}">{{$cat->name}}</a>
              @endforeach

            <br><a href="/post/{{$latest->slug}}/{{$latest->id}}">{!! strip_tags(link_to_action('PostsController@show', $latest->title, [$latest->slug, $latest->id])) !!}</a></h2>
            <span style="color: #b8b8b8">Paskeblta {{$latest->created_at}}</span>
            <hr>
          </div>
          @else
           <p>Nėra naujienų</p>
          @endif

          <div class="row">
            @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
            <a href="/post/{{$post->slug}}/{{$post->id}}">
            <img class="img-responsive" style="width: 352px; height: 180px" src="{!! url($post->image) !!}" alt=""></a>
              <h3 class="post" style="font-size: 1.4em; margin-top: 0; color: #666"><small style="color: red; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 11px">

              @foreach($post->category as $cat)
                {{$cat->name}}
              @endforeach

              </small><br><a href="/post/{{$post->slug}}/{{$post->id}}">{{strip_tags($post->title)}}</a></h3>
              <span style="color: #b8b8b8">Paskelbta {{$post->created_at}}</span>
              <br><br>
            </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->

            @endforeach
          </div><!--/row-->
        </div><!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->

        @include('comp.sidebar')
      </div><!--/row-->

      <hr>
@stop
```

Comment: Probably going to need some controller code to determine what is being passed to the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a check in the loop: if the current post is the same as the featured one, ignore it.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    @unless ($post == $latest)
        // rest of html goes here
    @endunless
@endforeach
```

If the objects aren't actually the same objects, just change the check accordingly - e.g. `@unless ($post->id == $latest->id)` or similar.